# tail -f over network with Putty

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh, putty, tail

I want to see log files on a remote Linux machine on my network without having to manually ssh, cd to directory and tail -f the log file. I am using Windows and need to do this with Putty. Is there a script command that i can use to do this?

Comment: You don't need to `cd` - you can just `tail -f ${FULL_PATH_TO_FILE}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use putty's "Remote command" field in Connection ==> SSH section of configuration. If you save all with public key authentication in a specifi session profile, you'll have your tail starting when launching this profile.